# Sensitive AC detector circuit

Tags: ac, rectifier

I built a field mill based on this [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2-G1xPD0tI). This device generates a sine wave, where I am interested in the amplitude.

Once i have the peak, or average value (does not matter, but average would be better), I will send it over to an arduino data logger.

What circuit could I build to accomplish this task. This will be on a high altitude balloon launch in a few weeks, and need to find a circuit quickly for a high school high altitude balloon launch in less than two weeks.

The AC wave peak ranges from a bit less than  one hundred millivolts to a few volts, and the data logger will read values from 0 to 5 volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as far as I understand the field mill (not familiar with it, looks neat), you have a sinusoidal voltage at some frequency (couldn't read the time division on the scope), and you want to convert it to a value that an Arduino can read.

First off, it'd be helpful to know the absolute peak voltage this thing is going to generate in a thunderstorm or something. In the video, it looks like it goes above 5V.

Here's how I'd go about it:

First, clamp the input to a sane range. Let's say -0.7V to 15V. This will require some diodes (ideally two). This eliminates troublesome voltages that will ruin the rest of the circuit.

Next, run the signal through a precision peak detector (a regular peak detector outputs one diode drop below the input, and won't work for your low input voltages). This will eliminate the sine wave, and give you a slowly-varying (almost DC) voltage. [Here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01353A.pdf) is a helpful document for designing precision peak detectors. Googling will give you many more resource for designing precision peak detectors.

Feed this signal through a voltage divider (and maybe another low-pass filter to clean it up), and then into your datalogger's ADC. This assumes that the field mill output voltage range is actually more than the 0-5V ADC range (because that's what I saw in the video). If this is not true, you should add a small gain stage to scale the voltage appropriately.

Edit: WhatRoughBeast raises a good point: motor noise can disturb the peak detector circuit. So, an alternative:

Clamp the input, as before. Run the signal through a precision half-wave rectifier. Low-pass filter this signal, and run it into the ADC, amplifying or attenuating as needed.

Comment: Peak detector will respond to things like motor noise. Average or RMS would seem more robust.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Good point. If the output frequency is low enough, an LPF on the field output would clean that up. But yeah, it might even be sufficient to half-wave rectify and then LPF the heck out of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will research schematics and designs for RMS detectors and peak detectors, but I would be really grateful if someone could provide a schematic. I need to order parts from a quick shipper (digikey) tomorrow if we are going to make the launch. Are diodes sufficient for rectification, or am I going to run into issues with the barrier potential?

Comment: No, diodes are not going to work if the output is below ~300mV. This is why you need a precision rectifier circuit (I am starting to like WhatRoughBeast's suggestion even more now; use a half-wave rectifier and LPF). You can build a good half-wave rectifier with an op-amp and two diodes. [See here](https://www.site.uottawa.ca/~rhabash/ELG4135L8.pdf). Everything else is R and C. You might want some extra op-amps for gain/filtering. And make sure you've got power rails for your op-amps!